# facing a weird bootstrap behavior in chrome

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-devtools, web-deployment-project

I have a django-bootstrap project in which an html page has a dynamically generated table with data-toggle popovers on td elements. in firefox, opera and edge everything works perfectly fine and the popover show up, but in chrome they just don't. however when I copy paste the same code in a new blank html test page unrelated to the project it works (minus a few css issues for the rest of the page).
am really out of my wits end trying to understand the behavior I tried:

- emptying cache and hard reload multiple time no success
- forcing the state to trigger popover no success
- no errors/warnings showing up in console
- restart server and dev machine no success
- clear a week's worth of cache and browser history
- check if there is a chrome extension blocking it. (none am aware of since the test page is working fine)
- made sure my jquery bootstrap 4 cdn's are up to date

I really have no clue what to turn to to find the source of the behavior. what steps do you do you guys go through if an element is randomly not showing on your page or you going through unexpected behaviors

Comment: Have you tried `ctrl + reload` on your chrome? Maybe your new styles are not being applied yet.

Comment: @Martins yep it didn't work :(